# Difficulties in installing Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to install the Jupyter Notebook. 
I followed the instructions on the Jupyter website, namely those passing through `pip`:

```
pip install jupyter
```

But halfway through the process I get the following error:

```
Storing debug log for failure in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

Can someone help?

Python version:2.7.6

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: maybe do it as root? sudo pip install jupyter?

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

Comment: Please add this as a solution and mark it correct. Otherwise it hangs around as an unanswered question forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by just doing it as root:

```
sudo pip install jupyter
```